# Open the same window.location.origin in a new tab without cache

Tags: javascript

**Framework: Angular 1.4.8**

I want to create a new tab which takes the same `window.location.origin` that the old tab has. But I want to ensure that data is loaded from the server and not from cache.

There is a method to open the new tab: `window.open(window.location.origin)`.

But I can't find any option which disables cache [in the API reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open). I am looking for an option similar to `forcedReload` in the [window.location.reload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) method.

Comment: You could try appending an extra query parameter to the url you are opening (window.location.origin) with some unique value. That way you will force a cache-miss.

Comment: @Claudio If I try to insert some parameters, a new window is opened not a tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came with the following solution:

```
 ...
 browser.openNewCleanTab = function (forcedReload = true) {
   const openNewTab = function (url) {
     return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
       resolve(window.open(url));
     });
   };

   openNewTab(window.location.origin).then((newTab) => {
     newTab.location.reload(forcedReload);
   });
 };
```

Basically, it opens a new tab and then reloads is with `forcedRelod`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these meta tags to the page. It helps to load the page without using cache. I hope the project is in ASP.NET

```
<!-- HTTP 1.1 -->
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store"/>
<!-- HTTP 1.0 -->
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<!-- Prevents caching at the Proxy Server -->
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
```